# How to write path to files in Magento? File is not found, even when I set the absolute path

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

everyone!

I try to create custom application sending (to emails) form the site on Magento.

For doing it, I call post.php file in this way:

```
$('form#send-profile').submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var output = true,
                array = $(this).serialize();

        if (output) {
            $.post('post.php', array, function(data) {
                $('input[type="text"], textarea').val('');
            });
        };
    });
```

I`ve placed post.php into the root folder (and tried it with different folders too).

But I had this result in any conditions:
POST http://vescorte.com/post.php 404 (Not Found)

Maybe Magento has some special way to set paths? Tell me please, if you know how to cope with this problem.

Comment: Please use a link that isn't a known source of spam on Stack Exchange. https://example.com/ will do, or [my domain].com if you want to clarify that you own the server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , which version of magento do you use ?

Next, if you want to development any new function , you need create a module

try this link [magento-2-module-development](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/)

Comment: I use 1.9.2.4 version

Answer (score 0):

In the template file in which you mentioned `JS` code, you can mention the Magento `base URL` function to get full base URL like below:

```
$.post('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>post.php', array, function(data) {
    $('input[type="text"], textarea').val('');
});
```

Still if you face issue then try to remove all the code from `post.php` and run with simple text to check file request complete or not.